# What should I look for when buying a new road group set?

Tags: groupsets

I have a 2004 Litespeed Tuscany in very good condition—these titanium frames seem to be lasting forever!

It came with a Campy Centaur groupset which I have moved to another cheaper frame (my first attempt in pretending to be a bike mechanic with a fairly good success, not perfect but that would be another question :)).

What should I look for when selecting a new group set?  Will all groups fit?  Will I be able to use my existing wheels?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a rim brake group set with a comparable brake reach as before, which will happen automatically if the new one is also Campy because convetional Campy calipers have only come in one reach in the past decades.

If the new group is Campy then you can use a 12 or 11 speed cassette on your existing wheel without issue. If you switch to Shimano or SRAM you need a different freehub body, which may or may not be available to retrofit your existing wheel. Most third party Campy-compatible hubs that receive such long term parts support at all do have these available. The idea is also out there that 11 and 12 speed cog spacing respectively are close enough between SRAM/Shimano and Campy that it doesn't matter. I'm personally down on the idea of setting up a high-end bike like that and expecting optimal performance, but it does function.

All groupsets have ISO bottom bracket shell compatible cranks of one spindle type or another available, but some (SRAM) also have BB30/PF30 ones that won't fit your shell, so you'd need to choose the compatible BB/crank option in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

A 2000's frame will have a 130mm rear dropout spacing and a 68mm wide ISO threaded bottom bracket shell. Basically any modern rim brake groupset will bolt right on.

If the wheels are of the same vintage presumably they are made for 10 speed. Road 11 speed groups require a slightly longer 11 speed compatible freehub body. You basically have a choice of new rear wheel and 11 speed group or a 10 speed group.

All groupsets are pretty much the same in terms of functionality. More expensive groups are of course lighter and function a bit better. With Shimano you can of course mix components from the 11 speed groups. The only current 10 speed road group is Tiagra 4700. Nate that you cannot mix derailleurs or shifters from older 10 speed groups with 4700 as it uses a different derailleur actuation ratio.